# VBA issue - storing data in array from inputbox

Tags: vba

I'm new in VBA , so i would lile to store values from inputbox into array , i wrote the code below , then i tried define a array to store them , i got the issue with my VBA code , could you please help check ? any assist will be appreciated

```
Sub inpubox()
    Dim sn As String
    Dim em_ID As String
    Dim name As String
    Dim dept As String
    Dim hostname As String
    Dim loc As String
    sn = InputBox("Enter Laptop's Serial")
    em_ID = InputBox("Enter Colleague ID")
    name = InputBox("Enter Colleague Name")
    dept = InputBox("Enter Colleague department")
    loc = InputBox("Enter office location")
    'Xu li hostname
    hostname = "VN" & loc & sn
    sodong = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).row
    Dim arr6 As String
    arr6 =(sn,em_id,name,dept,hostname,loc)
           
End Sub
```

The error also attached
[image: array error]

Comment: Try .. `arr6 = split(sn&","&em_ID&","&name&","&dept&","&hostname&","&loc, ",")` .. this will give you 0 based arr6

Comment: You defined arr6 as a string. You need to define it as an array

Comment: Yes.. `Dim arr6() As String` will give you string type array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This direct entry in to the array through inputbox

```
Option Explicit
Sub inpubox()

Dim arr(1 To 6) As String, sodong as long
    arr(1) = InputBox("Enter Laptop's Serial")
    arr(2) = InputBox("Enter Colleague ID")
    arr(3) = InputBox("Enter Colleague Name")
    arr(4) = InputBox("Enter Colleague department")
    arr(6) = InputBox("Enter office location")
    
    arr(5) = "VN" & arr(6) & arr(1)

sodong = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
Sheet1.Range("A" & sodong).Resize(1, 6).Value = arr

End Sub
```

Just to add to brilliant answer from Алексей Р below - - -
We can use code like below to overcome the limitation of concatenation for arr(4) position (0 based).

```
Sub ShortCode()
arr = Array(InputBox("Serial"), InputBox("ID"), InputBox("Name"), _
      InputBox("Department"), "HostName", InputBox("location"))
arr(4) = "VN" & arr(5) & arr(0)
Sheet1.Range("A" & Sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(, UBound(arr) + 1) = arr
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Sub ShortCode()
    arr = Array(InputBox("Enter Laptop's Serial"), InputBox("Enter Colleague ID"), _
          InputBox("Enter Colleague Name"), InputBox("Enter Colleague department"), _
          InputBox("Enter office location"))
    Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(, UBound(arr) + 1) = arr
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice! I like compact pieces of code... Voted up.

Comment: .......................................Super clever!

Answer (score 1):

We need to:

1. define the array
2. fill the array
3. store the array in a row of cells

For example:

```
Sub inpubox()
    Dim sn As String
    Dim em_ID As String
    Dim name As String
    Dim dept As String
    Dim hostname As String
    Dim loc As String
    sn = InputBox("Enter Laptop's Serial")
    em_ID = InputBox("Enter Colleague ID")
    name = InputBox("Enter Colleague Name")
    dept = InputBox("Enter Colleague department")
    loc = InputBox("Enter office location")
    'Xu li hostname
    hostname = "VN" & loc & sn
    sodong = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    
    Dim arr(1 To 6) As String
    arr(1) = sn
    arr(2) = em_ID
    arr(3) = name
    arr(4) = dept
    arr(5) = hostname
    arr(6) = loc
    
    Sheet1.Range(Cells(sodong, 1), Cells(sodong, 6)) = arr
           
End Sub
```

Comment: No need to even create variables .. we can directly input values in array as `arr(1) = InputBox("Enter Laptop's Serial")` and `arr(6) = InputBox("Enter office location")` and `arr(5) = "VN" & arr(6) & arr(1)`

Comment: @Naresh  **Good Comment**  You are completely correct!

Comment: thank you all for your help :) . here is the best place for me can learn alot about programing skills.