# How to collect user input to an array in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, import

im trying to record a user input which is a list of words separated by commas. Which i need to store as an array. Here is my attempt, but i am not too good at this. Thanks!

```
    Dim arWords() As String
    myt = InputBox("Enter User Input")
    arWords() = Split(myt, ",")
        For X = 0 To UBound(arWords())
        myf = myf & arWords(X) & vbCr
    Next X
```

Comment: `arWords` is the array, since `Split` returns an array. Where else are you stuck?

Comment: Sometimes ... We just need to rub our eyes and look at the code again. Oops! Thank you!

Comment: @kyle It looks like you are trying to change `,` to next line, can't you just do `Replace(myt,",",vbCr)`?

Comment: I suggest using `vbNewLine` instead of `vbCr`. The former is OS-independent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA issue - storing data in array from inputbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68152421/vba-issue-storing-data-in-array-from-inputbox)

Comment: Instead of the `For...Next` loop you could e.g. use `myf = Join(arWords, vbLf)`. If the list is supposed to be single words, you may want to remove any 'accidental' space by using something like `myt = Replace(myt, " ", "")` before the 'split'.